# Using Display S, M, L, XL, 2XL instead of H1 -H6 for typography in a Design System Manager (DSM)

Tags: typography, style-guide, design-system, heading, tag-hierarchy

[image]I find using specific H1 - H6  is confining since different pages may need a different size H1 and so on. Also instead of making 2 sets for desktop and mobile this would work as one file. Does anyone work like this and use something similar in handoff?

Comment: What exactly is your UX problem?  You say you want to use alternatives to H1-H6, but you don't really explain what the problems with H1-H6 are.

Answer (score -2):

I happen to agree with the poster. I think the problem that we are mixing hierarchy with size, and you quickly come across a problem if you want to use a large size but not use an h1 for example. I try to think more on a component level, and think of the h1 of the component. I think ChatGPT says it better:

"Don't use H1-H6 tags for styling: Avoid using H1-H6 tags solely for styling purposes, such as to increase the size of text. Use CSS to style the text instead."

Comment: (a) Most of us don't seem to like ChatGPT in answers, for a *lot* of reasons; (b) One of the ways to use CSS is to use it *with* tags, such as h1 - h6 - i.e., so that h1 tags style a particular way.